# Как отсортировать vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>> по second.second (третий int)?

Tags: c++

Есть предположение, что возможно провернуть с `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp)`, но не понимаю, как задействуется/что означает третий параметр (гугл также не внес ясности)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В предположении, что вас интересует `vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>`, `cmp` может выглядеть примерно так, например:

```
bool cmp(const pair<int,pair<int,int>>& p1, const pair<int,pair<int,int>>& p2)
{
    return p1.second.second < p2.second.second;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Это ссылка на функцию вида `bool foo(const T& a, const T& b)`, где `T` — тип элементов сортируемого вектора.

Задача этой функции — проверить, упорядочены ли `a` и `b` по возрастанию. Иными словами, не превышает ли значение `a` таковое у `b` (говоря математическим языком — соблюдается ли условие `a < b`).

Comment: Не обязательно функцию, вполне можно функтор (например, лямбду). И сигнатура должна быть `bool (const T& a, const T& b)` вроде бы.

Comment: Типы аргументов исправил (за замечание спасибо), однако стоит ли нагружать новичка такими понятиями, как «функтор» и «лямбда-функция» (последнее, к тому же, отсутствует в стандартах 98-го и 2003-го годов)?

Comment: Ну, хотя бы показать возможность написать лямбду в качестве продвинутого использования? Я бы вообще написал «любая фигня, которую можно вызвать так: `const T& l; const T& r; bool v = fignya(l, r);`». Хотя это, наверное, чересчур. (Но в духе C++.)

Comment: А кто бы мне объяснил, как такой тип возможен - `vector<int,pair<int,int>>`?

Comment: @Harry, тут какая-то опечатка. Ну не может `vector` принимать вторым шаблонным аргументом пару, только класс управления памятью для элементов. Вероятно, имелось в виду всё же `vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >`.

Comment: @Arhad Вот-вот :) На что и намекаю.

Answer (score 4):

`cmp` это любой функциональный объект. Это может быть лямбда, указатель на функцию или объект класса у которого определен `operator()`. Этот функциональный объект должен принимать два объекта из сортируемого списка, и возвращать `bool`. Объект должен реализовывать операцию [строгого слабого упорядочения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Вот так это будет выглядеть на вашем примере:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>> IntIntInt;

struct Compare{
    inline bool operator()(const IntIntInt &x, const IntIntInt &y) const{
        return x.second.second < y.second.second;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<IntIntInt> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(5, std::make_pair(3, 4)));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair(9, 0)));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(8, std::make_pair(6, 7)));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(4, std::make_pair(2, 3)));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(3, std::make_pair(1, 2)));

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Compare());
}
```

PS:

> гугл также не внес ясности

Не сочтите за рекламу. Есть один [замечательный сайт](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) на котором можно подсмотреть описание всех алгоритмов, их аргументы, гарантии исключений, сложность и примеры использования.

Comment: Мне лично больше нравится [другой замечательный сайт](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).