# Сортировка вектора, состоящего из структур, по алфавиту

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

У меня есть структура:

```
struct studentTXT
{
    string name;
    string gender;
    string curse;
    string group;
};
```

Как отсортировать вектор, состоящий из таких структур, по алфавиту?

Я считываю с файла "INFO.txt" список студентов по данной структуре, после чего добавляю их все в вектор.

```
vector<studentTXT> AllStudent;

while (infodatr.read((char *)&KItxt, sizeof(studentTXT)))
{
    AllStudent.push_back(KItxt);
}
for (short i = 0; i < AllStudent.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "\n_____________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "Имя и фамилия студента: ";
    cout << AllStudent[i].name << endl << "Курс: ";
    cout << AllStudent[i].curse << endl << "Група: ";
    cout << AllStudent[i].group << endl;
}
```

Пробовал через `sort(AllStudent.begin(), AllStudent.end());`, но словил ошибку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отсортировать vector<pair<int,pair<int,int>>> по second.second (третий int)?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566664/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-vectorpairint-pairint-int-%d0%bf%d0%be-second-second-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-int)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно использовать перегрузку [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), принимающую предикат.

Добавляем определение функционального объекта предиката:

```
struct StudentCmp {
    bool operator()(const studentTXT& lhs, const studentTXT& rhs) const {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name;
};
```

Вызывать так:

```
sort(AllStudent.begin(), AllStudent.end(), StudentCmp());
```

Начиная с C++11 можно упростить, используя лямбда-функцию.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за готовое решение. Чем больше изучаю C++, тем больше осознаю свою ничтожность познания в данном языке(

Comment: @nait123321 пожалуйста. Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте галочкой слева от ответа.